# How to Send NSMutableDictionary to PHP Web Server

Tags: php, ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsurlsession

I've got an NSMutable Dictionary that has restaurant item names and their quantities. I'm trying to send this dictionary to a PHP web page that will be able to properly read it. I'm also sending additional parameters (separate from the dictionary) such as delivery details, username, etc as well.

Keep in mind that the PHP web page will not know which keys the dictionary has since it will be different depending on the restaurant. That's why I need to send the dictionary itself over and then have the PHP "decode" it so to speak.

Is there anyway to us `NSURLSession` or even `AFHTTPNetowrking` to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2):

Objective-c

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"foo": @"bar"};
[manager POST:@"http://example.com/resources.json" parameters:parameters success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {


NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);


// if you want to read any json simply do.
[responseObject objectForKey:@"my_json_key"];


} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];
```

PHP

```
  echo $_POST['foo'];
```

Remember to import the library to your project https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking